# airflow not loading operator tasks from file other then DAG file

Tags: airflow

Normally we define the Operators within the same python file where our DAG is defined (see [this](https://airflow.apache.org/tutorial.html) basic example). So was I doing the same. But my tasks are itself BIG, using custom operators, so I wanted to have a polymorphism structured dag project, where all such tasks using same operator are in a separate file. For simplicity, let me give a very basic example. I have an operator `x` having several tasks. This is my project structure;

```
main_directory
  ├──tasks
  |  ├──operator_x
  |  |   └──op_x.py
  |  ├──operator_y
  |  :   └──op_y.py
  |   
  └──dag.py
```

op_x.py has following method;

```
def prepare_task():
    from main_directory.dag import dag
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_inner_date',
        bash_command='date',
        dag=dag)
    return t2
```

and the dag.py contains following code;

```
from main_directory.tasks.operator_x import prepare_task

default_args = {
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'on_failure_callback': gen_email(EMAIL_DISTRO, retry=False),
    'on_retry_callback': gen_email(EMAIL_DISTRO, retry=True),
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 5, 10)
}
dag = DAG('test_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=dt.timedelta(days=1))

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = prepare_task()
```

Now when I execute this in my airflow environment and run `airflow list_dags` I get the desired dag named `test_dag` listed, but when I do `airflow list_tasks -t test_dag` I only get one task with id `print_date` and NOT the  one defined inside the subdirectory with ID `print_inner_date`. can anyone help me understand what am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code would create cyclic imports. Instead, try the following:

`op_x.py` should have:

```py
def prepare_task(dag):
    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id='print_inner_date',
        bash_command='date',
        dag=dag)
    return t2
```

`dag.py`:

```py
from main_directory.tasks.operator_x import prepare_task

default_args = {
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'on_failure_callback': gen_email(EMAIL_DISTRO, retry=False),
    'on_retry_callback': gen_email(EMAIL_DISTRO, retry=True),
    'start_date': dt.datetime(2019, 5, 10)
}
dag = DAG('test_dag', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=dt.timedelta(days=1))

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = prepare_task(dag=dag)
```

Also make sure that `main_directory` is in your `PYTHONPATH`.